# Ошибка при переносе yii2 на хостинг?

Tags: yii2

Делал проект используя Yii2 basic на локальном сервере, теперь нужно это перенести на хостинг, как это сделал:
1. Перенес базу на БД хостинга.
2. Перенес файлы проекта на хостинг.

Теперь при переходе по ссылке, мне показывается ошибка:

PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Trait 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapWidgetTrait' not found

Почему? И если не правильно сделал, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте слеши в другую сторону поставить.
\ => /

Comment: Может версия php не поддерживающая трейты? Т.е.ниже 5.4....

Comment: Если вы использовали composer, то удалите папку vendor и выполните команду _composer install_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что на Git не все файлы были залиты с локального сервера